# ASP.NET Formview not correctly Updating

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm converting my website from Classic ASP to ASP.net and outside of a few bumps, I've had no problems until today. But I am learning on the fly.

I'm trying to update a record in a formview and every time I do, I get the following error: "Must declare the scalar variable "@FirstName"".

I've googled and searched, and can't see what I'm doing wrong. I'm sure there's something little that I'm doing incorrect.

```
      <asp:FormView ID="formRecruit" runat="server" DataSourceID="sourceRecruit" 
        EnableModelValidation="True" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" Width="100%" runat="server">         
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell Width="50%">
                <asp:Table ID="Table2" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow2" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Table ID="Table3" Width="100%" runat="server">  
                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow3" runat="server">
                        <asp:TableCell>Name:</asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell><%#Eval("FirstName") %></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell><asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" ID="LinkButton1" /></asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" Width="100%" runat="server">         
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell Width="50%">
                <asp:Table ID="Table2" Width="100%" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow2" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell>
                <asp:Table ID="Table3" Width="100%" runat="server">  
                    <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow3" runat="server">
                        <asp:TableCell>Name:</asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell><asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("FirstName") %>'/></asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TableCell><asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" ID="LinkButton1" /><asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ID="LinkButton2" CausesValidation="false" /></asp:TableCell>
                    </asp:TableRow>
                </asp:Table> 
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sourceRecruit" runat="server" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Players] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Players] SET [FirstName] = @FirstName WHERE [ID] = @ID"> 
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="ID" Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but try to have the `SqlDataSource` this way and see if it works:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sourceRecruit" runat="server" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBCS %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Players] WHERE ([ID] = @ID)" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Players] SET [FirstName] = @FirstName WHERE [ID] = @ID"> 
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter QueryStringField="ID" Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

You may also want to try converting the `asp:Table`, `asp:TableRow` tags etc to their HTML equivalent. It's been quite some time since I last worked with ASP.NET, but if I remember right, the controls somehow does not play well with data sources when you put them inside some other server controls.

Comment: I appreciate the help. When I add that, I no longer get the error. But no matter what I put into the textbox (txtFirstName), a NULL value is saved into the field.

Comment: @cunjiva: I've updated the answer above. If that don't help, then I'm not really sure what's the better way of doing it declaratively. You could always hand code so that the `FirstName` parameter gets updated correctly, but I think you would prefer not to do that if it's possible, right. :)

Comment: I converted the asp:Table tags to HTML and it worked! Thanks. I also pulled the updated parameter.